# How do I remove name and dtype from pandas output

Tags: python, pandas

I have output that looks like this:

```
nutrition_info_256174499 = df1.loc[:"Salt" , "%Reference Intake*"]

print (nutrition_info_256174499)

Typical Values
Energy                5%
Fat                   1%
of which saturates    1%
Carbohydrates         7%
of which sugars       2%
Fibre                  -
Protein               7%
Salt                  6%
Name: %Reference Intake*, dtype: object
```

What must be done to remove both Name and dtype at end of output?

Comment: df1[["Salt" , "%Reference Intake*"]] .. try this i.e. give column name as list

Comment: @Tokci You've got the syntax a little off: `"Salt"` is supposed to be the endpoint of a slice. I posted [an answer with a working version of this solution](/a/73696285/4518341) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use the [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) attribute.

**Example:**

```
In [158]: s = pd.Series(['race','gender'], index=[1,2])

In [159]: print(s)
1      race
2    gender
dtype: object

In [160]: s.values
Out[160]: array(['race', 'gender'], dtype=object)
```

**You can convert to a list or access each value:**

```
In [161]: list(s)
Out[161]: ['race', 'gender']
```

Answer (score 9):

For printing with preserving index you can use [`Series.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2.23, 0.23, 2.3]},
    index=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
s = df.loc[:'x2', 'b']    
print(s.to_string())
```

Output:

```
x1    2.23
x2    0.23
```

Comment: This is exactly what he doesn't want

Comment: @SundeepPidugu OP asks for "removing name and dtype from pandas output" and shows a print to standard-output as example. Note that the example in the accepted answer lacks the column-name since it's not a Series derived from a `DataFrame` to begin with. The accepted answer's "output" also removes the index, something the OP didn't ask for and doesn't remove the "dtype" at all until converting it to a list, which is a totally different story. That OP decided to accept an answer not doing what he really asked for is a different story and something you can't blame me for.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(nutrition_info_256174499.to_string())
```

that should remove `Name: %Reference Intake*, dtype: object` in your prints

Answer (score 0):

Simply converting the dataframe values to a list with `.tolist()` removes the dtype element. After you can just loop through the list to get the single values:

```
df_as_a_list = df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly what you want, but for what it's worth, if you put the column name in a list, you get a DataFrame out instead of a Series, with the name at the top instead of bottom and no dtype.

```
df1.loc[:"Salt", ["%Reference Intake*"]]
```

```
                   %Reference Intake*
Typical Values                       
Energy                             5%
Fat                                1%
of which saturates                 1%
Carbohydrates                      7%
of which sugars                    2%
Fibre                               -
Protein                            7%
Salt                               6%
```